# Intrinsic ratio when only height is known

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, horizontal-scrolling

Is there a horizontal equivalent of the [intrinsic ratio hack](https://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video)? That is, if the image is in a horizontal scrolling div, is it possible to determine the width that the image will occupy before it loads? The horizontal div is responsive, meaning that it resizes vertically based on the height of the viewport.

Edit: here's a quick demo: codepen.io/anon/pen/MrQGRy.

Comment: Could you add a working (or working in a wrong way) example to understand what you mean?

Comment: Here's a quick demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrQGRy. If I'm lazy loading the images, how can I calculate the width that the image will occupy before it loads?

Comment: It seems to me no way for arbitrary images. But if you able to check the size at the server,  maybe you could store the sizes in a database, or add them to filenames, and read before loading.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "read before loading"? Do you mean hard-coding the element's width?

Comment: Yes, `image-600x480.jpg`, something like this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following how that would be implemented in HTML/CSS. If I hard-code the width, the element will no longer be responsible, right? I definitely need it to be responsive.

Comment: Not exactly. You could just store the initial size, and then calculate the factual size depending on something what you want... But I think you should find other easier way with your layout; maybe it is not so necessary to know the width before load.

Comment: Without knowing the width, browsers default to the placeholder's dimensions (in this case 1px by 1px), meaning that all the images appear in the viewport on load and trigger lazy loading of all the images on the page, which partly defeats the purpose of lazy loading.

Comment: Best option I can think of is to use calc() to hard-code the width of img based on the max-height of its container and the image's ratio, and the in relation to vh when the viewport is the same height as the max-height of the container. I would need to add a lot of @media rules to use this when using the horizontal view, and additional ones when using the vertical layout. This seems really messy.

Comment: 1) calc() is not a reliable solution. 2) You don't know the image's ratio before load. Anyway, if the problem is the lazy loading, consider using of some JavaScript.

Comment: I do know the ratio, actually: width/height=ratio (this can be computed server side). So if i was using a 3:2 image, and the max-height of the parent container was 600px, the width would be 900/600*600=900px. Once the viewport is at least the height of the parent container, then it would be vh*ratio; e.g. 400px*1.5=600px. By inlining a calc() rule, this could be accomplished, it would just require at least 3 inlined @media rules per element..